# mac address changing

Tags: wireless

i have alfa awus036nh and for some commands i need to change it's mac address but it always gives me ERROR 
please help....!

when i do

```
    sudo ifconfig -a
```

it give me this:

```
    wlan1    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-C0-CA-28-9F-C7-33-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:1500  Metric:1
    RX packets:39069 errors:0 dropped:97 overruns:0 frame:0
    TX packets:34743 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
    collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
    RX bytes:42537771 (42.5 MB)  TX bytes:4448035 (4.4 MB)
```

Comment: where did you try to change it ?

Comment: do u mean with which command ? or what ?

Comment: check my answer if that applied on yours, if you already tried this and you faces an error, paste the error here to work around ;)

Answer (score 0):

if the topic of the question was HOW to change the mac address in Ubuntu, I believe you could simply go to network interfaces by entering the command in terminal:

`sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

and then edit the file to something like this at the end :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

at then end simply restart the networking service:

`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

if for some reasons that gives you error try this (or system restart):
`sudo service networking stop && sudo service networking start`

Comment: i got this:

* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...                                          RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
Failed to bring up eth0.

Comment: you would like to change your Ethernet cable interface or wireless ?

Comment: it's for wireless, am using ALFA AWUS036NH
and cant run it perfectly :(

Comment: so wifi should be soth like eth1 or wlan1 (check the result of your ifconfig which you already pasted here), change the three line of codes in the editor accordingly ;) and then if the restarting doesn't work try stop & start (look at my updated answer)

Comment: can you please check this link ?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/397806/mac-address-error

Comment: try out the written answer and let me know;)

Comment: okay i will .... :)

Comment: still the same problem :(
do you think the problem in the adapter driver ?

Comment: sorry for the sluggish reply, well maybe, try to send an email to the company and ask for the ubuntu driver if they have