# MAC address error : Device or resource busy

Tags: wireless

please can anybody explain this when am using the following commands ?

```
    mohammad@dv6-Notebook:~$ sudo -i

    root@dv6-Notebook:~# airmon-ng stop wlan1



    Interface   Chipset     Driver


    wlan0       Unknown     iwlwifi - [phy0]

    wlan1       Unknown     rt2800usb - [phy1]
                               (monitor mode disabled)


    root@dv6-Notebook:~# macchanger --mac 01:02:03:04:05:06 wlan1

    Permanent MAC: 00:c0:ca:28:9f:c7 (Alfa, Inc.)

    Current   MAC: 00:c0:ca:28:9f:c7 (Alfa, Inc.)

    ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 2):

It is saying two things, "interface up or not permission" this means that you may need to:

```
sudo machanger
```

Or that the "Device or resource is busy".

Maybe something like:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo airmon-ng stop wlan1
```

then run `sudo machanger`

and to get it up again.

```
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
sudo airmon-ng start wlan1
```

Comment: should i write 

        "sudo ifconfig wlan1 down"

before "macchanger" command ?

Comment: @user230142 you may need to `sudo macchanger` or make sure that wlan1 is not up/busy.

Comment: jmunsch thank you but still the same problem :( i really dont know what's my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop network manager service:

   ```
   service network-manager stop
   ```
2. Take down you network interface:

   ```
   ifconfig wlan0 down
   ```
3. Now change your mac address using mac changer:

   ```
   macchanger -r wlan0
   ```
4. Start network manager and network interface:

   ```
   service network-manager start  
   ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```

Comment: For me the key was to **not** stop and start network-manager, because it would reset the MAC address to default. Thus only down and up on the network interface worked for me.